# How do you rest the origen for my armature

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, snapping, origin

I've started animating and just noticed the my rigs origen is in the wrong place what I'd like to do is move the oregen back to my rig and not the rig to the origen.

Comment: If you want to move the origin of your armature to its geometry(?), go into the header menu > Object > Origin > Origin to Geometry

Comment: thank you for your suggestion moonboots.So It doesn't seem to work because my object is linked into the scene I'm working on, is there another way to go about doing this.

Comment: if you mean that you've imported it as a linked object, I guess you either need to make it local, or you need to edit the original object in its original file?